# Cannot create FB Application - Pixel Warning

Tags: facebook

I am on the page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
I am trying to add a new App. When I click the button, put in a name, my email, and category, I click to create, and nothing happens. According to the dev console, I am getting the following error:

Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple different pixels were detected on this page

> Stop!
>
> This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you
>   to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or "hack"
>   someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your
>   Facebook account.
>
> See https://www.facebook.com/selfxss for more information.

I cannot find ANY information on how this would be happening, seeing as how I am on an actual FB page.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that having "FB" in the App name blocked it.